# Linking a string with a login

Tags: c#, string, authentication

Im currently making a basic payroll system.

So far I have put all the employee names into a string and an If statement because they all have different hourly rates.

My problem at the moment is linking the same string to the login, so when the employee enters their name and clicks 'login' the program will be able to match the name to the hourly rate when they calculate their weekly hours, tax, pay etc.

Is there a solution/method for this?

```
string[] employeenames = new string[] { "Jordan", "Ryan", "Dan", };
            decimal payRate = 0.0M;
            for (int i = 0; i < employeenames.Length; i++)
            {
                if (employeenames[i] == "Jordan")
                {
                    payRate = 7.20M;
                }
                else if (employeenames[i] == "Ryan")
                {
                    payRate = 9.47M;
                }
                else if (employeenames[i] == "Dan")
                {
                    payRate = 13.27M;
                }
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question, are you trying to get the users logged in name then compare it with the database?

Comment: Can you post some code of your attempts ?

Comment: You should use a database and compare the database info with their login name. Please post the code you have so far

Comment: Sounds like you're describing a database. The description of what you have and what you're trying to do is *extremely* vague, however. Please show your code and explain what the specific problem is.

Comment: You are basically asking how to design a login system, which given that you aren't even using standard OOP yet, you are a *long* ways from being ready for. Please try to narrow down your questions, as its way too broad as is.

Comment: Sorry! So above is my string and if statement. So for example say 'Jordan' logged in, the program would then recognise his hourly pay of 7.20. At the moment, the result im getting is 13.27 regardless of whom I login as @ZachM.

Comment: So the right way to do this would be to store these name/payrate pairs in a database and build a model that you populate with these values.  Then build a list of these models which you could then itterate over: `EmployeeList(x => x.Name == userLoggedIn)`.  In your current example you are simply always going to get the last value as you are not comparing the array with some login but just looping over it and grabbing the last entry every time.

Comment: @TheBiz because at last iteration it matches `if (employeenames[2] == "Dan")  Since "Dan" is the last item in array
`

Comment: Apologies, ive just posted some of my code @izuhu

Comment: Yeah pretty much! Im just wondering if there is a possibility to link 'employeenames' and the login together. @BradleyDotNET

Comment: @TheBiz Of course there is, but how to do so in a reasonable way from where you are is beyond the scope of a stack overflow question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the better way to do this would be to use the following:
Create a class that houses every employee you could want

```
public class Employee{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public double PayRate {get;set;}
}
```

You can then add employees to a list made out of this class like this:

```
var employeeList = new List<Employee>();//This list should be populated from the database, below is just proof of concept showing the search syntax
    employeeList.Add(new Employee{ Name = "John", PayRate = 33.00});
    employeeList.Add(new Employee{ Name = "Steve", PayRate = 2});
    employeeList.Add(new Employee{ Name = "Bert", PayRate = 22.99});
```

The upshot here is you can write a data access method to populate this list from a database.

This will allow you to query against this data in a more meaningful way:

```
var userLoggedIn = "Steve";
    var foundAmmount = employeeList.FirstOrDefault (x => x.Name == userLoggedIn).PayRate;
```

The above code returns 2.

Comment: Ive been told to put it all in a class before, thanks this really helped!

Comment: Although this will work better than an if/else, this information should really be stored in a database of some form. What happens when an employee gets a raise? You'll have to change the hardcoded values, rebuild and release the application. Not very maintainable.

Comment: Very correct, the class list should be populated by some data access method.  This was simply proof of concept to get the ball rolling.  I made note of this in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Although the better option is to use a Database, you can use a `switch` statement instead.

```
string loginName = "";
decimal payRate = 0.0 + "M";
switch (loginName){
            case "Jordan":
                payRate = 7.20 + "M";
                break;
            case "Ryan":
                payRate = 9.47 + "M";
                break;
            case "Dan":
                payRate = 13.27 + "M";
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid login name");
                break;
        }
```

If you are only using a name to login with, this will be fine. However if you plan on using a password alongside the name, use a database.

Comment: This would be not maintainable if more users are added to the list.

Comment: @ZachM. Correct, neither would the OP's original code. However for a very small company this would be okay.

Comment: I understand that, but I would rather push the OP away from writing shoddy code and give them a better alternative.  You are correct however that it may suit their needs, it's just not a great way to solve the problem.

Comment: @ZachM. I totally understand what you mean